# how to convert raw json into the html table

Tags: javascript, html, json

Trying to convert json data into the form of html table. My json has no fixed headers and I am expecting to generate table like the following

```
<table border="1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Region </td>
    <td colspan='3'>Actual Generation (MU) during May </td>
    <td colspan='3'>Actual Generation (MU) during April to May </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2019 </td>
    <td>2018 </td>
    <td>% Growth </td>
    <td>2019 </td>
    <td>2018 </td>
    <td>% Growth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NORTHERN </td>
    <td>29521.05 </td>
    <td>27985.52 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>54304.43 </td>
    <td>50907.64 </td>
    <td>6.67 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WESTERN </td>
    <td>44690.15 </td>
    <td>41351.13 </td>
    <td>8.07 </td>
    <td>87706.37 </td>
    <td>80765.73 </td>
    <td>8.59 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SOUTHETRN </td>
    <td>22545.38 </td>
    <td>22628.38 </td>
    <td>-0.37</td>
    <td>45377.46 </td>
    <td>46334.83 </td>
    <td>-2.07</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EASTETRN </td>
    <td>18178.82 </td>
    <td>17338.96 </td>
    <td>4.84 </td>
    <td>35297.22 </td>
    <td>34040.56 </td>
    <td>3.69 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NOTRTH-EASTETRN </td>
    <td>1766.76 </td>
    <td>1455.27 </td>
    <td>21.40 </td>
    <td>3040.42 </td>
    <td>2578.04 </td>
    <td>17.94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IMPOTRT FTROM BHUTAN </td>
    <td>344.8 </td>
    <td>312.06 </td>
    <td>10.49 </td>
    <td>584.5 </td>
    <td>335.37 </td>
    <td>74.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GTRAND TOTAL </td>
    <td>117046.96 </td>
    <td>111071.32 </td>
    <td>5.38 </td>
    <td>226310.40 </td>
    <td>214962.17 </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Currently using the following code to do that, but not getting expected result.

```js
let datatable = '<table border="1"><tr>';
const trArray = [];
Object.entries(newdata).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let tr = key.substring(0, key.lastIndexOf('TD'));
  if (trArray.includes(tr)) {
    datatable += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
  } else {
    datatable += '</tr><tr><td>' + value + '</td>';
  }
  trArray.push(tr);
  this.prevtr = tr;
});

datatable += '</tr></table>'
//console.log(datatable)
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = datatable;
```

```html
Expected
   <table border="1">
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Region </td>
        <td colspan='3'>Actual Generation (MU) during May </td>
        <td colspan='3'>Actual Generation (MU) during April to May </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2019 </td>
        <td>2018 </td>
        <td>% Growth </td>
        <td>2019 </td>
        <td>2018 </td>
        <td>% Growth</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NORTHERN </td>
        <td>29521.05 </td>
        <td>27985.52 </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>54304.43 </td>
        <td>50907.64 </td>
        <td>6.67 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>WESTERN </td>
        <td>44690.15 </td>
        <td>41351.13 </td>
        <td>8.07 </td>
        <td>87706.37 </td>
        <td>80765.73 </td>
        <td>8.59 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SOUTHETRN </td>
        <td>22545.38 </td>
        <td>22628.38 </td>
        <td>-0.37</td>
        <td>45377.46 </td>
        <td>46334.83 </td>
        <td>-2.07</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EASTETRN </td>
        <td>18178.82 </td>
        <td>17338.96 </td>
        <td>4.84 </td>
        <td>35297.22 </td>
        <td>34040.56 </td>
        <td>3.69 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NOTRTH-EASTETRN </td>
        <td>1766.76 </td>
        <td>1455.27 </td>
        <td>21.40 </td>
        <td>3040.42 </td>
        <td>2578.04 </td>
        <td>17.94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>IMPOTRT FTROM BHUTAN </td>
        <td>344.8 </td>
        <td>312.06 </td>
        <td>10.49 </td>
        <td>584.5 </td>
        <td>335.37 </td>
        <td>74.29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GTRAND TOTAL </td>
        <td>117046.96 </td>
        <td>111071.32 </td>
        <td>5.38 </td>
        <td>226310.40 </td>
        <td>214962.17 </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<hr/>
Actual <div id="output"></div>
<script>
  const newdata = {
    "TR3TD1": "Region\n\n",
    "TR3TD2": "Actual Generation (MU) during May \n",
    "TR3TD5": "Actual Generation (MU) during\nApril to May\n\n",
    "TR4TD3": "2019\n",
    "TR4TD6": "2018\n",
    "TR4TD7": "% Growth\n",
    "TR4TD8": "2019\n",
    "TR4TD9": "2018\n",
    "TR4TD10": "% Growth",
    "TR5TD1": "NORTHERN\n\n",
    "TR5TD2": "29521.05\n",
    "TR5TD3": "27985.52\n",
    "TR5TD4": "",
    "TR5TD5": "54304.43\n",
    "TR5TD6": "50907.64\n",
    "TR5TD7": "6.67\n",
    "TR6TD1": "WESTERN\n\n",
    "TR6TD2": "44690.15\n",
    "TR6TD3": "41351.13\n",
    "TR6TD4": "8.07\n",
    "TR6TD5": "87706.37\n",
    "TR6TD6": "80765.73\n",
    "TR6TD7": "8.59\n",
    "TR7TD1": "SOUTHETRN\n\n",
    "TR7TD2": "22545.38\n",
    "TR7TD3": "22628.38\n",
    "TR7TD4": "-0.37",
    "TR7TD5": "45377.46\n",
    "TR7TD6": "46334.83\n",
    "TR7TD7": "-2.07",
    "TR8TD1": "EASTETRN\n\n",
    "TR8TD2": "18178.82\n",
    "TR8TD3": "17338.96\n",
    "TR8TD4": "4.84\n",
    "TR8TD5": "35297.22\n",
    "TR8TD6": "34040.56\n",
    "TR8TD7": "3.69\n",
    "TR9TD1": "NOTRTH-EASTETRN\n\n",
    "TR9TD2": "1766.76\n",
    "TR9TD3": "1455.27\n",
    "TR9TD4": "21.40\n",
    "TR9TD5": "3040.42\n",
    "TR9TD6": "2578.04\n",
    "TR9TD7": "17.94",
    "TR10TD1": "IMPOTRT FTROM BHUTAN\n\n",
    "TR10TD2": "344.8\n",
    "TR10TD3": "312.06\n",
    "TR10TD4": "10.49\n",
    "TR10TD5": "584.5\n",
    "TR10TD6": "335.37\n",
    "TR10TD7": "74.29",
    "TR11TD1": "GTRAND TOTAL\n\n",
    "TR11TD2": "117046.96\n",
    "TR11TD3": "111071.32\n",
    "TR11TD4": "5.38\n",
    "TR11TD5": "226310.40\n",
    "TR11TD6": "214962.17\n",
    "TR11TD7": ""
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you'd use some code to do that - creating tr's and td's as required

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: You seem to be missing some colspans in the generated table

Comment: Here is a working version https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n0ac3w9d/

Comment: `if (trArray.includes(tr)) {
    datatable += \`<td${[1,2].includes(i)?' colspan=3' : ''}>${value}</td>\`;
  } else {
    datatable += \`</tr><tr>${i===3?'<td></td>':''}<td>${value}</td>\`;
  }`

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, working fine for the present json, but i am also trying to do this for dynamic json because the response i am getting from server would not be the same.
Thank you again mplungjan.